# Reading checkboxes using webmatrix/razor

Tags: sql, razor, webmatrix

I'm having trouble with checkboxes on my site.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
@{
Layout = "~/_SiteLayout.cshtml";

WebSecurity.RequireAuthenticatedUser(); 

var db = Database.Open("StayInFlorida");

var rPropertyId = Request.QueryString["PropertyID"];

var Propertyinfo = "SELECT * FROM PropertyInfo WHERE PropertyID=@0";
var qPropertyinfo = db.QuerySingle(Propertyinfo, rPropertyId);

if(IsPost){
var sql = "INSERT INTO PropertyInfo (FePool, FeJac, FeGames) VALUES (@0, @1, @2) WHERE PropertyID=@3";
db.Execute(sql, Request["check1"], Request["check2"], Request["check3"], rPropertyId);
}
}

<form method="post">

<div>
<input type="checkbox" name="check1" value="true"  /> 
  Value 1
<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="check2" value="check2" /> 
  Value 2
<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="check3" value="check3" /> 
  Value 3
<br/>


<div>
<input type="submit" name="buttonSubmit" value="Submit" />
</div>
</form>
```

What I need to be able to do is check 3 columns in my database, and see if they are set to true (the columns are set as "bit"). If they are, then I want the checkbox to be shown as checked. I also want to be able to toggle these checkboxes and post "true" or "false" using a form, to post into the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `WHERE` clause in your `INSERT` statement which makes no sense. If you are inserting, you create a new row. I suspect you intend to `UPDATE` an existing row in which case your SQL should be:

```
"UPDATE PropertyInfo SET FePool = @0, FeJac= @1, FeGames = @2 WHERE PropertyID=@3"
```

If a checkbox is not checked, nothing will be included for that checkbox in the Request.Form collection. If it is checked, the value passed is "on" by default, or whatever you have specified in the "value" attribute. For check1, that will be "true". For check2, that will be "check2". You need to establish whether the checkbox was actually included in the Request.Form collection and then set the values you want to commit to the database accordingly. If you want to pass `true` or `false` depending on whether the checkbox was checked, you can do this:

```
var c1 = !Request["check1"].IsEmpty();
var c2 = !Request["check2"].IsEmpty();
var c3 = !Request["check3"].IsEmpty();
var sql = "UPDATE PropertyInfo SET FePool = @0, FeJac= @1, FeGames = @2 WHERE PropertyID=@3";
db.Execute(sql, c1,c2,c3,rPropertyInfo);
```

Now that you have a series of booleans, you can use those to determine whether the checkbox is checked or not by using [Conditional Attributes](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/201/Cleaner-Conditional-HTML-Attributes-In-Razor-Web-Pages):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="check1" checked="@c1" /> Value 1<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="check2" checked="@c2" /> Value 2<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="check3" checked="@c3" /> Value 3<br/>
```

If you want to preset the values of the checkboxes from a query, you do that prior to the IsPost block:

```
var rPropertyId = Request.QueryString["PropertyID"];
var Propertyinfo = "SELECT * FROM PropertyInfo WHERE PropertyID=@0";
var qPropertyinfo = db.QuerySingle(Propertyinfo, rPropertyId);
bool c1 = qPropertyinfo.FePool;
bool c2 = qPropertyinfo.FeJac;
bool c3 = qPropertyinfo.FeGames;
```

Obviously you don't need `var` in front of the `c1 - c3` variables in the IsPost block now.

Comment: thanks Mike, that worked perfect, and yes, i was trying to UPDATE, not INSERT. Bit of a lack of concentration there. So now i can tick the boxes and insert "true" into the database, how do i check if a box should be ticked already when i first load the page? i'm assuming some sort of @if statement connected to each checkbox?

Comment: but that method doesn't query the database to check if it's value is set to "true" does it?

Comment: No. You would have to add that code yourself and set the values of c1 etc based on the result of your query.

Comment: ok, so in my code above, i already run the query to get that info from the database (qpropertyinfo), but how do i set the values of c1 etc? would it be an @if statement?

Comment: Hi Mike, do you have any feedback about this? as i said, it's half working now, which is good.

Comment: The value of qPropertyInfo.FePool should be used for c1. It will either be true or false. qPropertyInfo.FeJac  is c2 and so on. Updated again to reflect that.

Comment: Thanks Mike, yet again you've given me a great answer. The only issue i now have is that if one of these variables is not set to either true or false, the page errors. i'll have to think of a way to set them all to false when the SQL record is first created. Thanks again

Comment: In fact, when i try and set the "default value" to false, it tells me that "default values cannot have column references"? what's that all about?

Comment: It's difficult to know what the problem is without seeing your code.

Comment: Hi Mike, the code isn't the problem, the problem is if i go into webmatrix database manager, i can't set the "default value" of these columns to "false"? seems a bit odd, if the only options for the column is either true or false?

Comment: Make sure the type for the column is bit and set the default value to 0. But the error you get about performing runtime bindings on null  references will go away if you do `bool c1 = qPropertyinfo.FePool ?? false;`